# Archiving many old Git projects into a single repo

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I've inherited ~150 Git repos at my new job, and my goal is to remove them from the local server where they presently reside and migrate everything into BitBucket.

Alas, most of these repos are only being kept around for legacy purposes and I don't really want to create a new BB repo for each and every one of them. Ultimately, I want to create a new repo called "DeepFreeze" that stores the more useless of these old repos in one centralized place, with them still accessible but practically invisible as a result.

There seems to be two main ways to go about this:

1. Subtree merge them all into DeepFreeze.
2. Add them as submodules.

Subtree Merge seems the most obvious, but I get the impression that will only add a single branch to the new repo.

Submodules thus seem to be the better option, but I worry the old projects won't effectively be stored with my new repo, and cloning DeepFreeze and then doing a "git submodule update" will fail when attempting to pull from the soon-to-be-deleted bare repos on the soon-to-be-repurposed local server.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to create a repository for each repo? Wouldn't a script do that for you easily?

Comment: @Colin -- It's more just to keep everything organized. I don't want to scroll through 150 archaic repos every time I load up BitBucket, but they have to go *somewhere*.

Comment: But where will the history of the repositories go then? Do you want to merge the history of each repo in one big repo? Do you need to keep the history at all (if not, why bother with git?)? I can tell you right now that submodules won't be the solution you seek as you will still need those repo to be somewhere (ie. 150 archaic repos in bitbucket).

Comment: Additionally, what do you want to do with the branches. Do you want to keep every branch and keep every repository in the exact same state?

Comment: "Do you want to keep every branch and keep every repository in the exact same state?" -- Pretty much. Is that completely unreasonable? If so, it's probably okay to lose most of the history, or merge it with the bigger repo. Now that I think about it, even compressing each repo into its own zip and storing those in the archive would work.

Comment: Okay, I think that solution would be probably a better way to handle things. You can execute a `git fsck && git prune && git gc --aggressive` in each of your repos too remove everything that isn't useful and reduce the repositories to a minimal size, and archive that.

Another solution would be creating a new account in BitBucket that will contain every repository so they're not always there, but are still available if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just zipping each of them and adding those zip files to the DeepFreeze repo. Works well enough.